# Neo4j / REST batch concurrency issue

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4j REST Batch API for the relationship insertion. I do the insertion from multiple instance and sometimes I get BatchOperationFailedException with empty message.

After the investigation I wrote a little program which shows a problem. It seems that rest API doesn't handle the concurrency issues.

So, I have created a console application that starts 10 threads, 5 threads execute first query and the another 5 threads execute second query.

The First query adds the relationship to the node **11** and then to the node **12**.
The second query adds the relationship to the node **12** and then to the node **11**.

And, I got the errors. **BUT** : if both queries will have the same order (both add the relationship to 11 and then to 12 or both add relationship to 12 and then to 11) Everything works perfectly.

I am getting the errors like this:

```
{
  "message" : "",
  "exception" : "BatchOperationFailedException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.domain.BatchOperationFailedException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.invoke(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:63)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.performRequest(BatchOperations.java:188)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.BatchOperations.parseAndPerform(BatchOperations.java:159)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.batch.NonStreamingBatchOperations.performBatchJobs(NonStreamingBatchOperations.java:48)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.batchProcess(BatchOperationService.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.BatchOperationService.performBatchOperations(BatchOperationService.java:71)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)" ]
}
```

The queries which get errors:

1.

```
[{"id":1,"method":"POST","to":"/node","body":{"Label":" ","Type":"USER","CreationDate":1369404750,"UserId":"{UserId}"}},

{"id":2,"method":"POST","to":"{1}/relationships","body":{"to":"/node/11","type":"INTERACTS","data":{"Label":"Label1","CreationDate":1258421809}}},

{"id":3,"method":"POST","to":"{1}/relationships","body":{"to":"/node/12","type":"INTERACTS","data":{"Label":"Label2","CreationDate":1258421809}}}]
```

2.

```
[{"id":1,"method":"POST","to":"/node","body":{"Label":" ","Type":"USER","CreationDate":1369404750,"UserId":"{UserId}"}},

{"id":2,"method":"POST","to":"{1}/relationships","body":{"to":"/node/12","type":"INTERACTS","data":{"Label":"Label1","CreationDate":1258421809}}},

{"id":3,"method":"POST","to":"{1}/relationships","body":{"to":"/node/11","type":"INTERACTS","data":{"Label":"Label2","CreationDate":1258421809}}}]
```

And the program:

```
    static string text1 = null;
    static string text2 = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(@"C:\git\PerformanceTest\Perf\1.txt");
        StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(@"C:\git\PerformanceTest\Perf\2.txt");
        text1 = sr1.ReadToEnd();
        text2 = sr2.ReadToEnd();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(InsertUsers1);
            thread2.Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Thread thread2 = new Thread(InsertUsers2);
            thread2.Start();
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.Join();
    }


    private static void InsertUsers1()
    {
        //while (true)
        //{
            Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            string newCommand = text1.Replace("{UserId}", r.Next(1000000, 100000000).ToString());

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            //request.Timeout = _timeout;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newCommand);
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    string queryResult = null;
                    Console.WriteLine("1");
                    using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            queryResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(5));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogException("InsertBatch1", e);
                Console.WriteLine("e1");
            }
        //}
    }

    private static void InsertUsers2()
    {
        //while (true)
        //{
            Random r = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            string newCommand = text2.Replace("{UserId}", "46239");

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:7474/db/data/batch");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;
            //request.Timeout = _timeout;
            try
            {
                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(newCommand);
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    string queryResult = null;
                    //Thread.Sleep(10);
                    Console.WriteLine("2");
                    using (var responseStream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            queryResult = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(5));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogException("InsertBatch2", e);
                Console.WriteLine("e2");
            }
        //}
    }

    private static void LogException(string methodName, Exception ex, string request = null)
    {
        if (ex is WebException)
        {
            try
            {
                string neoError = new StreamReader((ex as WebException).Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine("Neo4jContext." + methodName + " - Request error " + neoError);
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Neo4jContext." + methodName + " - Request error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Neo4jContext." + methodName + " - Request error");
        }
    }
```

**Question:** does anybody has experienced the same issue? How do you handle this issue? How we can insert relationship without concurrency problem and with a good performance at the same time?

P.S. : In doc about batch insertion (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html) there is note that batch insertion is not thread safe.
But we use REST API (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html) and there is no words about concurrency issues and I assumed that everything should work fine.

P.S. : I have tested it on Neo4j 1.9 and 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a deadlock, and the exception should say that.

Can you check `data/logs` and `data/graph.db/messages.log` if they contain the deadlock exception?

On deadlock you usually retry the operation that failed.

Comment: Thank you, I have checked data/logs and found deadlock message. I will rewrite code to avoid the deadlocks (just sort the commands) and also implement retry logic.